# How to play against a friend?

Tags: dota-2

My friend and I are interested in playing a public match together but in **opposite teams.**

Yes, I am aware this can be done in a lobby with bots but I really don't enjoy bot matches so I was wondering if this is possible?

Comment: I don't play dota2 myself but I'm quite sure that this is not possible. I mean you could then communicate with your friend and he could feed intentionally to let you win easily, at least that's what some people would do for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible for the simple reason that it could be abused to raise the MMR of an account quickly by matching it with a friend who would lose on purpose.

As a matter of fact some people are abusing the region/language settings to get matched with their friend in the opposite team in order to get easy win but those people are quickly spotted on the leaderboard and their account banned.

Comment: There should be private tournament thingy that does not affect MMR... Yes, yes that's what we all need!

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that in a public match, but what you **can** do is set up a lobby, find 8 other players (maybe other friends, maybe you search for them in one of the thousands of dota 2 chats ingame, for that i'd recommend searching for a channel of your own origin, e.g. since I'm German i look in the German chatroom) and then let them all join your lobby.

This way, you can play a 5on5 against your friend. :)

Comment: Thanks. This is a great idea. Time to pump up my friend count now!